# How to upload APNS cert to azure portal

Tags: azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-web-app-service

I have a .p12 apns cert that I would like to use in my azure hosted app. In my localhost, I have everything set up in the appsettings.Development.json file. Which includes the cert's path and its password.

I can update the appsettings in the azure portal, but now sure where to upload the actual cert.

Comment: You may refer to this https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/Configuring-a-certificate-for-APNS-on-the-Azure-platform and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I assume that you have created a notification hub and configured authentication with APNS using the .p12 push certificate.

Configure your notification hub with APNS information

1. Under **Notification Services**, select **Apple (APNS)**.
2. Select **Certificate**.
3. Select the **file icon**.
4. Select the **.p12** file that you exported earlier.
5. Specify the correct **password**.
6. Select **Sandbox** mode. Only use the **Production** if you want to send push notifications to users who purchased your app from the store.

For more information, you can see this tutorialL [Push notifications to iOS apps using Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started#configure-your-notification-hub-for-ios-push-notifications)

Comment: May i know if the issue get resolved? If the answer is helpful, please accept it, :)